# Passing pointer to array instead of array

Tags: c++, arrays

when I have a function that takes an array for example

```
void foo(std::vector<double> array)
{
something
}
```

and I first create a pointer to some array

```
std::vector<double> *array_pointer;
```

then point it at an array

```
array_pointer = &array;
```

and pass it to the function as

```
foo(*array_pointer);
```

do I get the same as if I would pass the array i.e.

```
foo(array);
```

?

Comment: Yes, you should. Have you tried running it?

Comment: The issue of using the pointer has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: Yous seem to be seriously confused. What you want is probably a reference:parameter: `void foo(std::vector<double>& array)`

Comment: well I have a long code and am looking for a mistake now and this is the only place i can imagine it at the moment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You would be better suited to make a reduced-but-complete program that demonstrates your current problem (a [mcve]) and asking a question based on it.

Comment: `std::vector` is not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

In

```
void foo(std::vector<double> array)
```

`array` is passed by value. `foo` will make a copy of the passed parameter and operate on the copy. Whatever you do to `array` in `foo` will not be observed by the caller because it has a different `array`.

`foo` cannot be called with a pointer. Note that you had to dereference the pointer, get the the object pointed at, with `*array_pointer` to call `foo` rather than pass the pointer. This has the effect of putting you right back where you started.

If your problem is with the caller not getting an updated `array` after `foo` has returned, consider passing `array` by reference:

```
void foo(std::vector<double> &array)
```

Now no copy takes place and `foo` can directly modify the `array` provided by the caller.